# Как усовершенствовать алгоритм, чтобы выполнялся для всех случаев, а не только для частного случая, который дан в условии

Tags: python

Выписав первые шесть простых чисел, получим 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 и 13. Очевидно, что 6-ое простое число - 13.

Какое число является 10001-ым простым числом?

```
from math import *
def Simple (n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    if n == 2:
        return True
    limit = sqrt(n)
    div = 2
    while div <= limit:
        if n % div == 0:
            return False
        div += 1

    return True

ind = 0
j = 0
numbers = [i for i in range (13, 10000000)]
while ind <= 10001:
    if Simple(numbers[j]) and ind <= 10001:
        print (numbers[j])
    ind += 1
    j += 1
```

Comment: Надо искать простые числа, а не проверять в диапазоне, является ли очередное число простым. И нельзя ограничиваться диапазоном - требуемое может оказаться больше границы.

Comment: @Akina То есть есть нужно создать переменную и она будет простым числом после каждого прохода ее увеличивать?

Comment: Надо запоминать все найденные простые числа - это ускорит и упростит поиск следующего простого числа. А несколько первых (2,3,5 и 7) можно вообще захардкодить.

Comment: Захардкодить? Это как ? И еще не совсем понимаю, как это запоминать?

Comment: *Захардкодить? Это как ?* Это сразу определить массив для простых с заполненными первым 4 значениями, а не пустой (ну или сразу вставить первые 4). *как это запоминать?* `simplenumbers[].append`

Comment: [Возможно вам будет интересно...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962194/%d0%91%d1%8b%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5-n)

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import *
def Simple (n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    if n == 2:
        return True
    limit = sqrt(n)
    div = 2
    while div <= limit:
        if n % div == 0:
            return False
        div += 1

    return True

Simple_Nums = [2,3,5,7,11,13]
num = 14
while len(Simple_Nums) != 10001:
    if Simple (num):
        Simple_Nums.append (num)
    num += 1

print (max(Simple_Nums))
```

Comment: Не надо увеличивать div на 1, а надо на 2 (начав с 3). простые числа нечетные и нет смысла проверять их делимость на 2, 4, и т.д.  Еще лучше проверять делимость на простые числа из списка Simple_Nums (решето Эратосфена) - если число не делится на 3, то он не делится и на 6, 9 и т.д.

Comment: Точно так же num надо увеличивать на 2 (начав с 15). Тем самым вдвое сократится количество вычислений

Comment: Вам @Эникейщик дело говорит - воспользуйтесь решетом Эратосфена или другим алгоритмом (например решетом Аткина или решетом Сундарама). [Различные имплементации решета Эратосфена](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Python)