# Быстрые способы нахождения всех простых чисел меньше N

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, оптимизация, простые-числа

Какие существуют алгоритмы наиболее быстрого нахождения всех простых чисел меньше N кроме всем известных:

- [Решето Эратосфена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0)
- [Решето Аткина](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%90%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0)
- [Решето Сундарама](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0)

И какие существуют быстрые реализации на Python (Vanilla, Numpy, etc.)?

[Наивная реализация решета Эратосфена:](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Python)

```
def eratosthenes2(n):
    multiples = set()
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        if i not in multiples:
            yield i
            multiples.update(range(i*i, n+1, i))
```

[Аналогичный вопрос в англоязычной версии SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n)

PS идея создания данного вопроса связана с постоянно появляющимися *новыми* вопросами об эффективной реализации нахождения всех простых чисел меньше N.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В качестве ответа я решил сравнить самые удачные реализации из [ответов на данный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n) и сделать замеры времени (для этого я использовал [модуль `reporttime`](https://gist.github.com/zed/4276624#file-reporttime-py) из [этого ответа @jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/775750/211923):

## primes.py

```html
import numpy
from math import sqrt, ceil


def rwh_primes(n):
    """ Returns  a list of primes < n """
    # (c) Robert William Hanks - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035188/5741205
    sieve = [True] * n
    for i in range(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if sieve[i]:
            sieve[i*i::2*i]=[False]*((n-i*i-1)//(2*i)+1)
    return [2] + [i for i in range(3,n,2) if sieve[i]]


def rwh_primes1(n):
    """ Returns  a list of primes < n """
    # (c) Robert William Hanks - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035188/5741205
    sieve = [True] * (n//2)
    for i in range(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if sieve[i//2]:
            sieve[i*i//2::i] = [False] * ((n-i*i-1)//(2*i)+1)
    return [2] + [2*i+1 for i in range(1,n//2) if sieve[i]]


def rwh_primes2(n):
    """ Input n>=6, Returns a list of primes, 2 <= p < n """
    # (c) Robert William Hanks - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035188/5741205
    n, correction = n-n%6+6, 2-(n%6>1)
    sieve = [True] * (n//3)
    for i in range(1,int(n**0.5)//3+1):
      if sieve[i]:
        k=3*i+1|1
        sieve[      k*k//3      ::2*k] = [False] * ((n//6-k*k//6-1)//k+1)
        sieve[k*(k-2*(i&1)+4)//3::2*k] = [False] * ((n//6-k*(k-2*(i&1)+4)//6-1)//k+1)
    return [2,3] + [3*i+1|1 for i in range(1,n//3-correction) if sieve[i]]


def primesfrom3to(n):
    """ Returns a array of primes, 3 <= p < n """
    # (c) Robert William Hanks - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035188/5741205
    sieve = numpy.ones(n//2, dtype=numpy.bool)
    for i in range(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if sieve[i//2]:
            sieve[i*i//2::i] = False
    return 2*numpy.nonzero(sieve)[0][1::]+1


def primesfrom2to(n):
    """ Input n>=6, Returns a array of primes, 2 <= p < n """
    # (c) Robert William Hanks - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035188/5741205
    sieve = numpy.ones(n//3 + (n%6==2), dtype=numpy.bool)
    for i in range(1,int(n**0.5)//3+1):
        if sieve[i]:
            k=3*i+1|1
            sieve[       k*k//3     ::2*k] = False
            sieve[k*(k-2*(i&1)+4)//3::2*k] = False
    return numpy.r_[2,3,((3*numpy.nonzero(sieve)[0][1:]+1)|1)]


def sieveOfEratosthenes(n):
    """sieveOfEratosthenes(n): return the list of the primes < n."""
    # Code from: <dickinsm@gmail.com>, Nov 30 2006
    # http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/msg/f1f10ced88c68c2d
    if n <= 2:
        return []
    sieve = list(range(3, n, 2))
    top = len(sieve)
    for si in sieve:
        if si:
            bottom = (si*si - 3) // 2
            if bottom >= top:
                break
            sieve[bottom::si] = [0] * -((bottom - top) // si)
    return [2] + [el for el in sieve if el]


def sieveOfAtkin(end):
    """sieveOfAtkin(end): return a list of all the prime numbers <end
    using the Sieve of Atkin."""
    # Code by Steve Krenzel, <Sgk284@gmail.com>, improved
    # Code: https://web.archive.org/web/20080324064651/http://krenzel.info/?p=83
    # Info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin
    assert end > 0
    lng = ((end-1) // 2)
    sieve = [False] * (lng + 1)

    x_max, x2, xd = int(sqrt((end-1)/4.0)), 0, 4
    for xd in range(4, 8*x_max + 2, 8):
        x2 += xd
        y_max = int(sqrt(end-x2))
        n, n_diff = x2 + y_max*y_max, (y_max << 1) - 1
        if not (n & 1):
            n -= n_diff
            n_diff -= 2
        for d in range((n_diff - 1) << 1, -1, -8):
            m = n % 12
            if m == 1 or m == 5:
                m = n >> 1
                sieve[m] = not sieve[m]
            n -= d

    x_max, x2, xd = int(sqrt((end-1) / 3.0)), 0, 3
    for xd in range(3, 6 * x_max + 2, 6):
        x2 += xd
        y_max = int(sqrt(end-x2))
        n, n_diff = x2 + y_max*y_max, (y_max << 1) - 1
        if not(n & 1):
            n -= n_diff
            n_diff -= 2
        for d in range((n_diff - 1) << 1, -1, -8):
            if n % 12 == 7:
                m = n >> 1
                sieve[m] = not sieve[m]
            n -= d

    x_max, y_min, x2, xd = int((2 + sqrt(4-8*(1-end)))/4), -1, 0, 3
    for x in range(1, x_max + 1):
        x2 += xd
        xd += 6
        if x2 >= end: y_min = (((int(ceil(sqrt(x2 - end))) - 1) << 1) - 2) << 1
        n, n_diff = ((x*x + x) << 1) - 1, (((x-1) << 1) - 2) << 1
        for d in range(n_diff, y_min, -8):
            if n % 12 == 11:
                m = n >> 1
                sieve[m] = not sieve[m]
            n += d

    primes = [2, 3]
    if end <= 3:
        return primes[:max(0,end-2)]

    for n in range(5 >> 1, (int(sqrt(end))+1) >> 1):
        if sieve[n]:
            primes.append((n << 1) + 1)
            aux = (n << 1) + 1
            aux *= aux
            for k in range(aux, end, 2 * aux):
                sieve[k >> 1] = False

    s  = int(sqrt(end)) + 1
    if s  % 2 == 0:
        s += 1
    primes.extend([i for i in range(s, end, 2) if sieve[i >> 1]])

    return primes


def sundaram3(max_n):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n-in-python/2073279#2073279
    numbers = list(range(3, max_n+1, 2))
    half = (max_n)//2
    initial = 4

    for step in range(3, max_n+1, 2):
        for i in range(initial, half, step):
            numbers[i-1] = 0
        initial += 2*(step+1)

        if initial > half:
            return [2] + list(filter(None, numbers))
```

Замеры времени:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

os.chdir(r'C:\work\project\primes_timing')

import primes
from reporttime import get_functions_with_prefix, measure

funcs = get_functions_with_prefix('', module=primes)
    
d = {}
for n in [10**3, 10**4, 10**5, 10**6]:
    m = measure(funcs, args=[n])
    d[n] = pd.Series({b:a for a,b in m}) 
r = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Вывод на печать:

```
name                     time ratio comment
primesfrom3to         21 usec  1.00 [1000]
sieveOfEratosthenes 40.1 usec  1.91 [1000]
rwh_primes          50.2 usec  2.39 [1000]
primesfrom2to       63.6 usec  3.02 [1000]
sundaram3           91.8 usec  4.37 [1000]
rwh_primes1          110 usec  5.25 [1000]
rwh_primes2          129 usec  6.12 [1000]
sieveOfAtkin         286 usec 13.61 [1000]

name                     time ratio comment
primesfrom3to       69.3 usec  1.00 [10000]
primesfrom2to        172 usec  2.48 [10000]
sieveOfEratosthenes  375 usec  5.41 [10000]
rwh_primes           447 usec  6.45 [10000]
rwh_primes2          503 usec  7.26 [10000]
rwh_primes1          577 usec  8.33 [10000]
sundaram3           1.22 msec 17.66 [10000]
sieveOfAtkin         2.2 msec 31.72 [10000]

name                     time ratio comment
primesfrom3to        306 usec  1.00 [100000]
primesfrom2to        371 usec  1.21 [100000]
sieveOfEratosthenes 3.82 msec 12.47 [100000]
rwh_primes          3.94 msec 12.84 [100000]
rwh_primes2         4.19 msec 13.68 [100000]
rwh_primes1         5.37 msec 17.53 [100000]
sundaram3           15.2 msec 49.57 [100000]
sieveOfAtkin        21.3 msec 69.47 [100000]

name                     time  ratio comment
primesfrom2to       2.29 msec   1.00 [1000000]
primesfrom3to       3.05 msec   1.33 [1000000]
rwh_primes2         38.7 msec  16.91 [1000000]
rwh_primes1         48.3 msec  21.12 [1000000]
rwh_primes          52.5 msec  22.96 [1000000]
sieveOfEratosthenes   61 msec  26.64 [1000000]
sieveOfAtkin         205 msec  89.64 [1000000]
sundaram3            245 msec 107.27 [1000000]
```

DataFrame с результатами:

```
In [67]: r
Out[67]:
                      1000      10000     100000    1000000
primesfrom2to        0.000064  0.000172  0.000371  0.002288
primesfrom3to        0.000021  0.000069  0.000306  0.003046
rwh_primes           0.000050  0.000447  0.003936  0.052516
rwh_primes1          0.000110  0.000577  0.005373  0.048307
rwh_primes2          0.000129  0.000503  0.004191  0.038678
sieveOfAtkin         0.000286  0.002197  0.021293  0.205074
sieveOfEratosthenes  0.000040  0.000375  0.003823  0.060955
sundaram3            0.000092  0.001223  0.015194  0.245407
```

график:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

r.T.plot(loglog=True, grid=True, figsize=(8, 6))
plt.xlabel('N - generate all primes below N')
plt.ylabel('Time in seconds')
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Разбор работы самой быстрой из известных мне [реализаций решета Эратосфена](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035188/5741205) на **Vanilla Python**,  т.е. без использования дополнительных модулей.

[(c) Bruno Astrolino E Silva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350331/robert-william-hanks) - я лишь добавил отладочную информацию:

```
def primes(n, verbose=0):
    """ Returns  a list of primes < n """
    # (c) Robert William Hanks - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035188/5741205
    def pr(*args):
        if verbose > 0:
            print(*args)
    sieve = [True] * n
    pr("все чётные числа игнорируются и будут пропущены при возврате...\n")
    for i in range(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if sieve[i]:
            pr('содержимое решета:\t{}'.format([x for x in range(3,n,2) if sieve[x]]))
            pr(f'i:{i} вычёркиваем все числа кратные "{i}", начиная с "{i}^2": {list(range(i*i, n, 2*i))}')
            sieve[i*i::2*i]=[False]*((n-i*i-1)//(2*i)+1)
            pr(f'sieve[{i}*{i}::2*{i}]=[False]*(({n-i}*{i-1})//(2*{i})+1)')
            pr('содержимое решета:\t{}'.format([x for x in range(3,n,2) if sieve[x]]))
            pr('*' * 60)
    return [2] + [i for i in range(3,n,2) if sieve[i]]
```

PS данная реализация очень эффетивно использует срезы и, благодаря этому, минимизирует число итераций цикла - в примере ниже для нахождения всех простых чисел меньше `50`, понадобилось всего три итерации цикла.

Вывод для `n=50`:

```
In [165]: primes(50, verbose=1)
все чётные числа игнорируются и будут пропущены при возврате...

содержимое решета:      [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49]
i:3 вычёркиваем все числа кратные "3", начиная с "3^2": [9, 15, 21, 27, 33, 39, 45]
sieve[3*3::2*3]=[False]*((47*2)//(2*3)+1)
содержимое решета:      [3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29, 31, 35, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49]
************************************************************
содержимое решета:      [3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29, 31, 35, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49]
i:5 вычёркиваем все числа кратные "5", начиная с "5^2": [25, 35, 45]
sieve[5*5::2*5]=[False]*((45*4)//(2*5)+1)
содержимое решета:      [3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49]
************************************************************
содержимое решета:      [3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49]
i:7 вычёркиваем все числа кратные "7", начиная с "7^2": [49]
sieve[7*7::2*7]=[False]*((43*6)//(2*7)+1)
содержимое решета:      [3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]
************************************************************
Out[165]: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47
```

Comment: Ссылка на "Bruno Astrolino E Silva" правильная, или только участник переименовался?

Comment: @0xdb, `Bruno Astrolino E Silva` - это реальное имя участника SO под "account": `Robert William Hanks` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле вывод к примеру суммы всех простых чисел до 2000000 занимает меньше 0,01 сек, этот код с реализацией решета Эратосфена я писал под конкретную задачу, но нахождение простых чисел в заданном диапазоне это довольно часто встречающаяся процедура:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <math.h>

main (){

int * pointer;
int i, ii;
int size=2000000;
long long int sum=2;
pointer = (int*) malloc (size*sizeof(int));
for (i=0;i<=size;i++)
    *(pointer+i)=i;
*(pointer+1)=0;
for (i=2;i<=size;i=i+2)
    *(pointer+i)=0;
for (i=3;i*i<size;i++){
    if (*(pointer+i)!=0) {
        for (ii=i*i;ii<size;ii=ii+i){
        *(pointer+ii)=0;
        } 
    }
}
for (i=0;i<size;i++){
    sum=sum+*(pointer+i);
}
printf ("Sum for %d elem is %lld", size, sum);
free (pointer);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нужен список `list` простых чисел для дальнейшей обработки то можно сделать таким образом, скорость просчета удовлетворительная. Этот алгоритм базируется на 2-х принципах:
1. Число является простым если не делится на предыдущие простые числа.
2. У составного числа делитель есть в пределах k / 2.
Вот мое решение:

```
my_list = [2]
for k in range(3, 100000, 2):
    i = 0
    while k > my_list[i]:
        if k % my_list[i] == 0:
            break
        if my_list[i] * 2 > k:
           my_list.append(k)
           break
        i +=1
print(my_list)
```

Comment: `"скорость просчета удовлетворительная"` - для n=10**5,  `%timeit primes(n)` - возвращает `3.71 ms ± 180 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`, а ваша функция - `8.02 s ± 28.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`. Разница в ~65 раз. Для бОльших `n` разница, скорее всего, будет еще больше