# Найти сумму всех простых чисел меньше двух миллионов

Tags: python, алгоритм

Почему прога очень долго выводит результат? Может есть какая-нибудь ошибка?

Сумма простых чисел меньше 10 равна 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17.

Найдите сумму всех простых чисел меньше двух миллионов.

```
from math import *
def PrimeNumber (n):
    if n == 1:
        return False
    if n == 2:
        return True
    limit = sqrt (n)
    div = 2
    while div <= limit: # По формуле, достаточно перебрать делители числа до квадратного корня самого числа
        if n % div == 0:
            return False
        div += 1
    return True

s = 2
a = 3
while a < 2000000:
    if PrimeNumber (a):
        s += a
    else:
        a += 2
print (s)
```

Comment: Потому что для определения простоты числа Вы используете факторизацию, а задача факторизации имеет высокую сложность. Думаю, для вашей задачи больше подойдёт [Решето Эратосфена](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0). Либо можете попробовать для определения простоты использовать вероятностные алгоритмы (тесты Ферма, Соловея-Штрассена, Люка, Миллера-Рабина), но они вернут вам **правильный** ответ с некоторой **вероятностью** (не 100%).

Comment: [похожий вопрос...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962194/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-n)

Comment: В данном случае с решетом более верный подход - он даст сразу все простые числа, а определение простоты боле выгодно для теста единичного числа или небольшого диапазона

Comment: алгоритм нахождения всех простых чисел до некоторого целого числа n, в данном случаем число n - это номер последовательности?

Comment: `n` - ограничение. В Вашем случае `n = 2*10**6`.

Comment: Я немного не понял,** Пусть A — булевый массив, индексируемый числами от 2 до n, 
изначально заполненный значениями true.** То есть в моем массиве 2кк элементов, И каждому дать значение True? Если да, то как , через цикл?

Comment: `nums = [True for _ in range(2*10**6)]`

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Спасибо

Comment: Да, можете .............

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/164567/ советую посмотреть. одни из самых бысрых способов. (у победителя особенно)

Answer (score 5):

[Берем функцию](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035188/5909792), которая возвращает простые числа через Решето Эратосфена, и суммируем их:

```
def primes(n):
    """ Returns  a list of primes < n """
    sieve = [True] * n
    for i in range(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if sieve[i]:
            sieve[i*i::2*i]=[False]*((n-i*i-1)//(2*i)+1)
    return [2] + [i for i in range(3,n,2) if sieve[i]]

print(sum(primes(2_000_000)))
# 142913828922
```

---

**UPD.** **@MaxU** предложил использовать оптимизированную версию функции получения простых чисел: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035188/5909792 . Она выглядит сложно, но в сравнении с предыдущей, она в 16 раз быстрее выдала результат на моей машине.

Comment: вашу реализацию можно ускорить минимум на порядок если: 1. сразу исключить все четные числа `for i in range(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2)`. 2) при нахождении в цикле простого числа вычеркивать все числа кратные данному простому числу используя срезы ([пример - функция `primes()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n/3035188#3035188)) ;-)

Comment: @MaxU, адище, а не функция :D

Comment: ага, добавил её в качестве ответа, но с отладочной/дополнительной  информацией, чтобы было понятнее как она работает...

Answer (score 4):

Для поиска простых чисел можно воспользоваться решетом Эратосфена, функция взята из [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188425/is-there-a-simple-algorithm-that-can-determine-if-x-is-prime-and-not-confuse-a/193605#193605) на английском StackOverflow

```
# Функция, реализующая решето Эратосфена
def iprimes_upto(limit):
    is_prime = [True] * limit
    for n in range(2, limit):
        if is_prime[n]:
           yield n
           for i in range(n*n, limit, n): # start at ``n`` squared
               is_prime[i] = False

# Получаем все простые числа до 2 миллионов
primes = list(iprimes_upto(2000000))
print(sum(primes)) # выводим сумму
> 142913828922
```

Comment: было бы еще неплохо указать [автора](https://stackoverflow.com/a/193605/5741205) ... ;-)

Comment: @MaxU, честно говоря, я не помнил точно, где взял это код :) Просто в своих примерах на компе нашёл. Спасибо, немного уточнил ответ

Answer (score 3):

[Вот очень эффективная реализация решета Эратосфена (c) Robert William Hanks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035188/5741205) - я лишь добавил отладочную информацию:

```
def primes(n):
    """ Returns  a list of primes < n """
    # (c) Robert William Hanks - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035188/5741205
    sieve = [True] * n
    print("все чётные числа игнорируются и будут пропущены при возврате...\n")
    for i in range(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if sieve[i]:
            print('содержимое решета:\t{}'.format([x for x in range(3,n,2) if sieve[x]]))
            print(f'i:{i} вычёркиваем все числа кратные "{i}", начиная с "{i}^2": {list(range(i*i, n, 2*i))}')
            sieve[i*i::2*i]=[False]*((n-i*i-1)//(2*i)+1)
            print(f'sieve[{i}*{i}::2*{i}]=[False]*(({n-i}*{i-1})//(2*{i})+1)')
            print('содержимое решета:\t{}'.format([x for x in range(3,n,2) if sieve[x]]))
            print('*' * 60)
    return [2] + [i for i in range(3,n,2) if sieve[i]]
```

Вывод для `n=50`:

```
In [165]: primes(50)
все чётные числа игнорируются и будут пропущены при возврате...

содержимое решета:      [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49]
i:3 вычёркиваем все числа кратные "3", начиная с "3^2": [9, 15, 21, 27, 33, 39, 45]
sieve[3*3::2*3]=[False]*((47*2)//(2*3)+1)
содержимое решета:      [3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29, 31, 35, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49]
************************************************************
содержимое решета:      [3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29, 31, 35, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49]
i:5 вычёркиваем все числа кратные "5", начиная с "5^2": [25, 35, 45]
sieve[5*5::2*5]=[False]*((45*4)//(2*5)+1)
содержимое решета:      [3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49]
************************************************************
содержимое решета:      [3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49]
i:7 вычёркиваем все числа кратные "7", начиная с "7^2": [49]
sieve[7*7::2*7]=[False]*((43*6)//(2*7)+1)
содержимое решета:      [3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]
************************************************************
Out[165]: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
numbers = []
s = 0
for i in range (n + 1): #Заполняем массив элентами от 0 до n
    numbers.append (i)

numbers[1] = 0 #Так как второй элемент массива это единица, а она не является ни простым, ни составным

i = 2 #В данном случае это индекс, то есть мы начинаем с 3 элемента, на месте которого стоит 2

while i <= n:
    if numbers[i] != 0:
        j = 2*i
        while j <= n:
            numbers[j] = 0
            j += i
    i += 1

numbers = set(numbers) #Избавляемся от повторяющихся нулей , но один останется
numbers.remove (0) #Теперь нулей нету
print (sum(numbers))
```