# Поиск простых чисел

Tags: python

Помогите, пожалуйста, хотя бы набросать основную часть, ибо в голову приходит только это:

```
if num == '1':
    print ('1 is not a prime number, actually')
else:
    if num == '2':
        print ('2 is a prime number, actually')
    else:
        if num == '3':
             print ('3 is a prime number, actually')
        else:
            if num == '4':
                print ('4 is not a prime number, actually')
```

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962194/%d0%91%d1%8b%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5-n)

Comment: Нашел ответ на данный вопрос благодаря комментарию пользователя выше. Для тех,кому интересно: [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962194/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-n).