# Эффективный алгоритм для вывода простых чисел

Tags: python, алгоритм, простые-числа

Пытаюсь вывести все простые числа до 1000. Не могу понять в чём проблема, но выводится только первое число:

```
def prime(x):
    d = 2
    while x%d!=0:
        d+=1
    return d==x
for i in range(1,1000):
    if prime(i):
        print(i, end='')
```

Comment: Решето Эратосфена.  https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: Вот таблица что б не искать https://dpva.ru/Guide/GuideMathematics/GuideMathematicsFiguresTables/SimpleFigures/SimpleFiguresPrint/

Comment: [похожый вопрос...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/962194/211923)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Быстрые способы нахождения всех простых чисел меньше N](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962194/%d0%91%d1%8b%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5-n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы обманываете, этот код вообще ничего не выводит. Но если заменить `range(1,1000)` на `range(2,1000)`, то выведет все простые до 1000.

А не выводит потому что цикл

```
while x%d!=0:
    d+=1
```

при х = 1 и начальном значении d =2 никогда не закончится.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так вот:

```
for n in range(2, 1001):
    if all(n % i != 0 for i in range(2, n)):
        print(n)
```

Для простых до тысячи нет смысла применять какие-то эффективные алгоритмы

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в использовании единицы - цикл внутри prime бесконечный получается

```
for i in range(2,1000):
```

и всё заработает