# Проект Эйлера. Задача 10 на С++

Tags: c++

Очень хотелось бы узнать на конкретном примере, существует ли более оптимизированное и быстрое решение данной задачи? Задача 10 сформулирована так:

> Сумма простых чисел меньше 10 равна 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17.
> Найдите сумму всех простых чисел меньше двух миллионов.

Моё решение (уходит несколько минут):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned long long sum = 2;
    const unsigned long long limit = 2000000;
    bool check;

    for (unsigned long long i = 3; i < limit; ++i) {
        check=false;
        for (unsigned long long j = 2; j < i; ++j) {
            if (i%j==0) {
                check=true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!check) {
            sum+=i;
            cout<<"Prime number "<<i<<" is being processed, current sum is "<<sum<<endl;

            }
    }

    cout<<"Sum of the prime numbers below "<<limit<<" is "<<sum;
}
```

Comment: Ну, как минимум, 1) нет смысла проверять чётные числа на простоту: `++i` -> `i += 2`, 2) достаточно проверять делители до корня из числа: `j < i` -> `j*j <= i`.

Comment: [Быстрые способы нахождения всех простых чисел меньше N](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/962194).

Comment: Невероятно сократило время выполнения, благодарю. Тогда и проверять делимость на чётные числа тоже не нужно, j = 2 -> j = 3 и ++j -> j+=2

Answer (score 1):

Если для любого числа вычёркивать числа ему кратные, то останутся только простые. Это идея которая лежит в основе [решета Эратосфена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    const uint64_t n = 2000000;
    uint64_t sum = 0;
    std::vector<bool> sieve(n + 1, true);
    for (uint64_t i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
        if (sieve[i]) {
            sum += i;
            for (uint64_t j = i * i; j <= n; j += i) {
                sieve[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << sum << '\n';
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 project_euler_10.cpp
>
> $ time ./a.out 
> 142913828922
>
> real  0m0.012s
> user  0m0.008s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Один из самых быстрых алгоритмов поиска простого число, это через pow. Вот в этом (линк) ответе уже дан полноценный хороший пример. И вам очень повезло что он дан как-раз на CPP.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/68809428

*ps: Зря не пользуетесь google, это сэкономило-бы вам кучу времени.*

**Добавленно спустя**

Ещё вот такой способ есть

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(long long n) {
    if (n < 2) return false;
    for(long long i=2; i<=sqrt(n); i++)
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}


int main() {
    for (int i=0; i<2000000; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            cout << i << " ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Тхэнкью. В том то и дело что быстро что-то загуглить не вышло, а ответили быстрее чем кажется. Да и останется будущим вопрошающим энивей. В следующий раз буду искать лучше!!

Comment: `Вот в этом (линк) ответе уже дан полноценный хороший пример` [Работает неверно](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b47fdf65728b8072).

Comment: @wololo Да и хватит *непосредственного применения* этого метода ("через `pow`" :)) очень ненадолго...